# Return value void * in a function

Tags: c, return-value, void-pointers

I was given a function whose return value is `void *`. I need to return two values from that function.

```
void * studentsCount(int *Arr, int len, int score, int *lessCount, int *moreCount) {
    if (Arr == NULL || len <= 0)
        return NULL;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++){
        if (Arr[i] < score)
            *lessCount++;
        else if (Arr[i] > score)
            *moreCount++;
    }
    return lessCount;  // <-- I need to return lesscount and morecount..!
}
```

How can I return both values using void pointer?

Comment: You maybe  want `(*lessCount)++;`

Comment: not sure why you'd return either of them since you're passing both by reference.

Comment: This function is already doing it. The pointers you pass will point to the values you need (well, with @BLUEPIXY correction).

Comment: ... but either the caller or the function must initialise their values.

Comment: Well as @EugeneSh. discussed above, you are already passing those values by reference. However if you really want both these values returned then you can create a simple structure, declare two integers and return address of that structure variable.

Comment: Who told you the function should return `void *`?  Based on everything else that's going on, this seems like a strange (even meaningless) choice.

Comment: @LinuxStuff: sort of, except for details like how is the structure allocated so it survives the return, and who frees it if it is `malloc()`'d, and why return `void *` instead of `struct pair_of_int` (or perhaps `struct pair_of_int *`)?

Comment: The normal way for a function to return two values is to do so via pointers, which is exactly what your function is already doing, via the `lessCount` and `moreCount` parameters.

Comment: Yeah,I got it thank you.I need not return as they are passed by reference.

Comment: BTW, you can avoid that nasty accident with `++` if you write `int *const lessCount` and `int *const moreCount`.  That would force you to sort out the precedence, either with `++*lessCount` or with `*lessCount += 1` or similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to `return` `moreCount` and `lessCount`, you just have to update their values inside the function.

As per return type `void *` is concerned, I would assume it signifies if the passed array is a "valid" array, if it is you may choose to return a non null value ( depends on how the `studentsCount` function is invoked ).

The caller should also make sure `moreCount` and `lessCount` points to a valid memory location, initialized to *proper* values

Answer (score 0):

No, you need to pass at least one of them by parameter.

Comment: Both are passed by pointer anyway.  It's possible to return multiple values via a structure type — which would be better than a `void *` return type.  Given that the code returns NULL when the array or the length are invalid, it seems likely the function should return the array (pointer to the start of the data) when it succeeds, though it is a slightly weird interface.

Answer (score 0):

You must pass the variables by reference when calling the function

```
studentsCount(<var Arr>,<var len>,<var score>,&<var lessCount>,&<var moreCount>);
```

In addition, you can not use the increment or decrement operators in a variable used by reference, because of they a pointer. Attached an example function code, with call by reference for variables, i hope, this help you

```
void ejemplo(int *valor1, int *valor2){
    int valor1_val=*valor1;
    int valor2_val=*valor2;
    printf("\nValues in Function\n");
    printf("Before Asignation\n");
    printf("Numero1 [%d]\nNumero2 [%d]\n",valor1_val,valor2_val);
    valor1_val++;
    valor2_val--;
    printf("After Asignation\n");
    printf("Numero1 [%d]\nNumero2 [%d]\n\n",valor1_val,valor2_val);
    *valor1=valor1_val;
    *valor2=valor2_val;
    printf("Return to Main Code\n\n");
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
   int numero1=100;
   int numero2=100;
   printf("In Main, before function call\n");
    printf("Numero1 [%d]\nNumero2 [%d]\n",numero1,numero2);
    ejemplo(&numero1,&numero2);
    printf("After function call\n");
    printf("Numero1 [%d]\nNumero2 [%d]\n",numero1,numero2);
    exit(0);
}
```